# Select a non dateformat value from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm using SQL Server and I have the following table:

```
+----------+---------+------------+
|  name1   |  name2  |    date    |
+----------+---------+------------+
| Value 1  | Value 2 | 123        |
| Separate | cols    | 01/12/2015 |
| aaa      | ssss    | 25/12/2015 |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

I'm focusing in the date column. This a `nvarchar` column.
I would select all the values from date's column that aren't in a date format.
So, I would select the `123` value because it isn't in a `dd-mm-yyyy` format.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEANME WHERE CHARINDEX('/',Date)=0
```